# Convert two rows to one row and two columns on dataframe in pandas using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Convert two rows to one row and two columns on dataframe using python.

**Input:**
[image]

**output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation to your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
filename = "assets/test.csv"
data = pd.read_csv (
    filename,
    skiprows=[0],
    header=None,
) 

X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
Y = data.iloc[:,-1].values

X = X.tolist()
Y = Y.tolist()
Z = []

for i in range(0,len(data),2):
    L = X[i]
    L.append(Y[i])
    L.append(Y[i+1])
    Z.append(L)

Z = np.array(Z)
data_ = pd.DataFrame(Z,index=None)
data_.to_csv("assets/test_.csv")
```

First the data (assuming will be stored in csv) will be read using pandas. Then, it will be segregated and converted to list for ease of manipulation. Later on the program is iterating for every other element in the list and appending to a new list. Finally the list is converted to numpy to be written to a new csv.

Note the following

- It is assumed that all even rows have their semi-duplicated underneath them.
- The headers are omitted but can be added by removing the attribute `skiprows=[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I made like this. You can add item_no 345 and 456 data. I've just used the sample data.
Code:

```
#import he library
import pandas as pd

# sample df from your data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "item_no" : ["123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123"],
    "department": ["cse", "cse", "cse", "cse", "cse", "cse", "cse", "cse"],
    "pincode": [528978, 528978, 528978, 528978, 528978, 528978, 528978, 528978],
    "column" : ["memory", "memory", "ram", "ram", "inch", "inch", "screws", "screws"],
    "value":["1tb", "10tb", "4gb", "8gb", "14", "148", "6", "9"]
})

# create new empty list
new_list = []

for idx, item in enumerate(df.values):
    for idx2, item2 in enumerate(new_list):
        if (item[0]==item2[0] and 
            item[1]==item2[1] and 
            item[2]==item2[2] and 
            item[3]==item2[3]):
            new_list[idx2] = [item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item2[4], item[4]]
    else:
        new_list.append([item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4]])
 
#filter new_list       
new_list = [x for x in new_list if len(x) > 5]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(new_list, 
    columns = ["item_no", "department", "pincode",  "column", "old_value", "new_value" ])
 
# print dataframe.
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  item_no department  pincode  column old_value new_value
0     123        cse   528978  memory       1tb      10tb
1     123        cse   528978     ram       4gb       8gb
2     123        cse   528978    inch        14       148
3     123        cse   528978  screws         6         9
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `groupby` :

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the first four lines of your data table
df=pd.DataFrame(
      {
      "item_no": ['123', '123','123','123'], 
      "department" : ["cse", "cse", "cse","cse"], 
      "pincode": ["528978","528978","528978","528978"], 
      "column":["memory", "memory", "ram","ram"], 
      "value" : ["1tb","10tb","4gb","8gb"]
      })

df_tmp = (df
            # Group by the first four columns
           .groupby(['item_no', 'department', 'pincode','column'])['value']

            # Aggregate by unique values and convert MultiIndex to single  
           .agg(['unique']).reset_index()
         )

# Then splitting the list of [old, new] into a temp df with new column labels
split_df = pd.DataFrame(df_tmp['unique'].tolist(), columns=['old', 'new'])

# Finally concatenating the original four columns with the temp df
df_new = pd.concat([df_tmp, split_df], axis=1).drop('unique', axis=1)
```

The output `df_new` looks like

```
  item_no department pincode  column  old   new
0     123        cse  528978  memory  1tb  10tb
1     123        cse  528978     ram  4gb   8gb
```